# Disable text cursor within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here are two fiddles: [fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/54QM2/3/) and [fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/54QM2/4/)

The only difference between the two is one CSS property in `.category`

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

When you click and drag one of the elements, the latter fiddle keeps the pointer cursor instead of changing to the text cursor (caret?).  I would like that to be the case!

The thing is, when I run the EXACT same HTML, CSS and JS in my browser (outside of JSFiddle), it no longer works and instead behaves like the first fiddle (which I don't want).

I had always understood that JSFiddle inherits the properties of the browser you are using, and so I am curious why the second fiddle works the way I would like it to, but the exact same code does not work when I run it in my browser.

Thoughts?  Or maybe solutions to keep the pointer cursor at all times?

Comment: I see pointers for both on Firefox.

Comment: I see pointers for both on Chrome as well

Comment: What is the jquery version you use "outside jsfiddle"

Comment: @gat yeah I just checked it in FF and it is a pointer on both, you're right.  But not the case on safari.  Interesting.

Comment: @SajithNair I am using JQuery V1.8.2

Comment: So you are telling, even with the css -webkit-user-select: none; you are seeing the text cursor in safari when you run the code outside jsfiddle???

Comment: Yessir, that is what's going on.  In Safari.  I've never had something work differently in JSFiddle before.

Comment: On chromium if I drag to the left on the first fiddle, i get the caret however the second doesn't seem to show a caret at all (dragging either direction), its interesting that viewing the source of the embedded result shows that the code is executing within an iframe so perhaps that is the cause of your altered behavior.

Comment: If you use jQuery UI it's quite simple! just use `disableSelection()` function

Answer (score 1):

after checking the source of the 3rd and 4th revisions your

`-webkit-user-select`

doesnt show in the 3rd revision but is visible in the 4th revision so, possibly just a miss-calculation?

[image]

Comment: It isn't supposed to be there in the 3rd revision.  I intentionally took it out to show the 'text cursor' case, and then put it in the 4th revision to show the 'pointer cursor' case.

Comment: ah then i misunderstood the question, my bad.